# Angular2 authentication - Type 'AsyncSubject<{}>' is not assignable to type 'AsyncSubject<boolean> - observables and typescript

Tags: javascript, authentication, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm new to observables and typescript so I'm messing something up. Here's my authentication component for angular2

```
// route-protection.service.ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  Router,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';


/*
 * Shared Utilities
 */
import {Authentication} from './authentication.service';
import {Logging} from '../../app-components/common/utility';

@Injectable()
export class RouteProtection implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService:Authentication,
              private router:Router) {

  }


  canActivate(next:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):boolean {
    return this.authService.checkAuth()
      .map(e=> {
        if (e) {
          return true;
        }
      }).catch(()=> {
        this.router.navigate(['/about'])
        return Observable.of(false)
      })
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
[default] ~/src/app-components/common/route-protection.service.ts:20:3 
    Type 'AsyncSubject<{}>' is not assignable to type 'AsyncSubject<boolean>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
[default] ~/src/app-components/common/route-protection.service.ts:29:12 
    Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

What does it mean? I am attempting to use angular2 and add 'route protection' so the routes can only be activated after authentication is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method returns and `Observable<boolean>` not a plain `boolean`:

```
  canActivate(next:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean> {
```

The actual signature of [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) is

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean>|boolean
```

which means both are allowed but your code actually returns `Observable<boolean>`

Comment: Thanks dude, that fixed it. No more typescript compile error.